# Getting a time string into the job.setall to set a crontab job in python

Tags: python, cron

I am trying to run a job at dawn and dusk everyday using crontab (which seems like the easiest way), as part of the dawn job I want to calculate dawn/dusk for the next day and modify the existing dawn and dusk jobs. I am using the astral module to do the calculation and get the time strings out into an array successfully but then getting them into a format that the crontab accepts is proving challenging.
Below is the code I am using:

```
today = datetime.date.today()
tomorrow = today + datetime.timedelta(days=1)
s = sun(city.observer, tomorrow)
dawn = s["dawn"]
dusk = s["dusk"]
My_cron_user = CronTab(user='root')
job = My_cron_user.new(command='python3 /home/DoorControl/DoorOpen.py', comment='DoorOpen')
job.setall(datetime(dawn[0:4], dawn[5:7], dawn[8:10], dawn[11:13], dawn[14:16]))
My_cron_user.write()
```

I have tried several methods to translate the dawn element (which comes out like this 2021-12-17 07:20:37.364901+00:00) of s into a format that job.setall will accept from splitting the string up (as above) through to using datetime, but cannot seem to get it right and hit several different types of errors. Any suggestions would be appreciated, thanks.

@karthiknair, so the below command seems to work and allows me to create the job.

```
#job.setall(datetime(2021, 12, 15, 7, 00))
```

The 7 cannot be 07 as that throws an error.

Matt

Comment: give an example of the kind of string you want

Comment: @karthiknair thanks, I have added a command that does seem to work into the initial description for clarification.